# Drupal Fields Ajax not working

Tags: entities, ajax

I have added fields to my entity via Field UI and trying to fire an ajax callback but it is not working.

This works

```
$form['customField'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
);

$form['customField']['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'just_test',
      'wrapper' => 'membership_suggestions',
);
```

But this does not ('field_member_first_name' is added to the entity via Field UI and is a text field)

```
$form['field_member_first_name']['#ajax'] = array(
    'event' => 'blur',
    'callback' => 'just_test',
    'wrapper' => 'membership_suggestions',
);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you used dev tools to check if the ajax is firing and if it is returning something?

Comment: Yes, I checked. It's not firing. After some searching I found the problem. The entity fields need to have [language][und] and all to attach the [#ajax]. I am now looking how to attach it.

Comment: It would be helpfiul to see the rest of `$form['field_member_first_name']` and maybe the form item with the wrapper 'membership_suggestions'

Answer (score 1):

Since the fields were attached via Field API, I have to do this way

```
$form['field_member_last_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#ajax'] = array(
    'event' => 'blur',
    'callback' => 'get_suggestion_by_name',
    'wrapper' => 'suggestions_by_name',
    'method' => 'html',
);
```